# Duplicating an object's attributes including Paperclip uploaded image Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, duplicates, paperclip

I am new to rails and trying to figure out why this isn't working!
I am trying to duplicate an object that belongs to another user, and make it mine. Everything works well but 2 things:
1. the image does information is duplicated but image shows up as broken

1. user can reduplicate the object over and over again.

My code:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController    
  def calee
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @image = @event.event_image
    if @event.user_id != current_user.id
      @event = @event.amoeba_dup
      @event.user_id = current_user.id
      @event.event_image = @image
      @event.save
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

I included the @image line in hopes to solve the attachment problem. When I inspect elements, shows like it should be finding th

Comment: Could you please paste the amoeba_dub method on Event?

Comment: Used this gem: https://github.com/rocksolidwebdesign/amoeba

Comment: Found a different way to do this without duplication, thanks for the help anyways Pedro :D

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
    class EventsController < ApplicationController    
      def calee
        @event = Event.find(params[:id])
        new_event = @event.dup
        new_event.user_id = current_user.id
        new_event.save
        redirect_to :back
      end
    end
```